# Possible Poltergeist memory leak - how to use session.driver.quit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, poltergeist

I think I'm running into a memory leak when running Rspec/ Capybara tests. At least, this reasonably high-specced Macbook Pro — and Chrome in particular — slows to an almost unusable crawl when tests are run.

Poltergeist mentions this as a [possible issue](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#memory-leak) (I am running JS tests).

The suggested fix is to include `session.driver.quit`, but where should this be included? Where is `session` defined by default?

When I include `session.driver.quit` after tests it causes errors.

Answer (score 0):

Under Capybara, the "session" is accessible using `Capybara.current_session` which can also be [aliased as `page`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/dsl.rb#L47) in the tests. So you might try the following:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
```

But I am not sure quitting will help you after the tests end (please tell us if it actually helped).

Comment: thanks @boraMa. So I assume the correct place to run this is after each test / open session?

Comment: Hmm, I'd love to tell you, but I don't know. When I put the `quit` in a `teardown` callback after each test, the tests started to fail miserably (the `quit` closes the stream from the browser). In our setup we also use Poltergeist with JS tests and I do not experience the issues you describe on a notebook with 8GB RAM and SSD. Even our test server with 4GB RAM seems to run the tests OK.

Comment: thanks @boraMa, i am also having the same problems you describe with `quit`. it could well be something else that is causing our memory leak. I'm really looking for a way to eliminate possible candidates, and Poltergeist seemed a likely candidate based on issues described. Welcome any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the link your provided - that only really applies if you're manually managing sessions (calling Session.new yourself) and is just advising to cleanup the sessions when done with them.  If you start calling `quit` when Capybara is managing the sessions you'll have all sorts of issues.  The better bet is to just make sure you're running the latest version PhantomJS (2.1.1 as of today) since that is most likely where any leaks would build up.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and used `page.driver.restart` to restart PhantomJS after each spec.

My PhantomJS memory usage is now consistently below 200mb (it used to reach >5Gb when running the whole suite).

```
  config.after(:each) do |example|
    if defined?(page) # page is not defined on non-JS tests
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      page.driver.restart
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```